# Get pictures from camera (using Adobe Flash?)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, browser, actionscript, camera

I was wondering if anyone knows of any Adobe Flash solution for getting all the pictures from a camera so I can automatically upload them to my website (when they visit my webpage).

Preferably this would be all in the web browser, but I'm not sure if that's possible.  If it isn't, is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Nope, you can only get files through the FileReference box, and that's a good thing because if what you are asking was allowed it would be very scary.

Comment: When you say **camera**, do you mean a webcam connected to your computer, or a real camera connected to your computer through USB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with AIR or a flash extender like MDM Zinc that produces desktop/mobile software.  But for very good security reasons you can not do this with flash on the web.  You could however do it the proper way of bringing up the FileReference box and letting the user choose file(s) to give you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no problems doing something like this from a desktop web camera.

You will have to request permission to use the camera and the user will be presented with a dialog indicating the site wishes to use the camera, but as long as they accept you'll be able to grab images from the camera.

First you'll need to initialise and attach the camera

```
var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
var video:Video = new Video(320,240);
video.attachCamera(cam);
addChild(video);
```

Then you'll need to create a bitmap data object:

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(video.width,video.height);
```

Then when you need to capture the camera you can just use the draw function:

```
bitmapData.draw(video);
```

I suggest you grab the jpg encoder from the [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) so you can encode it into a jpg and then send that to your server. The upload process is made much easier by using the [UploadPostHelper](http://marstonstudio.com/2007/10/19/how-to-take-a-snapshot-of-a-flash-movie-and-automatically-upload-the-jpg-to-a-server-in-three-easy-steps/) which is a great class to create multipart data forms:

```
ByteArray byteArray = JPGEncoder.encode( bitmapData );

var urlRequest : URLRequest = new URLRequest();
urlRequest.url = 'http://your.server.com/destination';
urlRequest.contentType = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + UploadPostHelper.getBoundary();
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
urlRequest.data = UploadPostHelper.getPostData( 'image.jpg', byteArray );
urlRequest.requestHeaders.push( new URLRequestHeader( 'Cache-Control', 'no-cache' ) );

// create the image loader & send the image to the server;
var urlLoader : URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
urlLoader.load( urlRequest );
```

And of course you can listen to the complete event and pass back any information from your server. Hope that helps.